# How to get EpicGame's navbar transitions when hovering over link?

Tags: html, css

When you hover over, say, 'News', a blue underline will pop-in. From what I've seen, it is actually a background with a height transition from 0px -> 5px. However, my code is unable to replicate it.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 28px 36px;
  background: black;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar li {
  padding: 0 8px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.navbar li::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: blue;
  transition: height .2s ease-in-out;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm definitely missing something obvious here, but I don't get it. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you did the most of the work, but you **should always keep in mind when you using pseudo-elements like [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) you have to declare `content` property** in it, otherwise it won't work at all. Then to make this work, you should just care about making the transition by putting initial `with` and `height` on `::before` then make the height element to the actual one in hover.

So your final code should be something like this:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 28px 36px;
  background: black;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar li {
  padding: 0 8px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.navbar li::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 50px;
  height: 0;
  background: blue;
  transition: height .2s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar li:hover::before {
  height: 5px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```